# Code in DOJO1.6 and DOJO1.4.3 working differently

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

I have the following code in DOJO1.6 and DOJO1.4.   In 1.6 version it is working fine but but is not working in 1.4. The tabbed menus are getting displayed as just list. Please help me so that the code works fine in DOJO1.4 also.

```
<script src="/portal_dojo/v1.4.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
<div style="width: 350px; height: 300px">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
        Lorem ipsum and all around...
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My second tab">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My last tab" closable="true">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `<body class="tundra">` (or the theme you want to use), and have included the CSS file for that theme?

Comment: Yes. Both were added. I am using tundra theme and added tundra.css

Answer (score 0):

Support for HTML5 style `data-dojo-xyz` attributes were added in 1.5, so they won't be recognized by Dojo 1.4.

So instead of `data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer"` you have to use `dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer"` (and equivalent for ContentPane, of course) for Dojo 1.4.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/froden/WyeRk/

Comment: @user1129605 Check out the jsfiddle link. Does it work in your browser? What are the differences between the jsfiddle and your code? Perhaps you can paste more of your code here. Are the tabs not instantiated at all, or do they just look wrong?

Comment: My code is working in JSfiddle. But not in my system. If I  have three tabs with test as tabone, tabtwo and tabthree..I get the following in output in a plain html page:    tabone  tabtwo tabthree in different lines. Thats all.

Comment: @user1129605 Hmm, very strange. It sounds like the TabContainer isn't being instantiated, but it's hard to tell why. Other dijits are working, and there are no errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I am not using any other widgets. I get a js error as '; expected' when I include dojo.xd.js. But I could not find where ; is missing.

Comment: @user1129605 Ah, interesting. I'm noticing that you are using the cross-domain version (xd), even though you have a local copy of Dojo. Could that be related? Have you tried using just dojo.js instead?